# Reformatting whitespace delimited command output

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to parse the output of `docker images` which is this:

```
<none>              <none>              efeea0b4d6fa        3 hours ago         812.9 MB
crew/test           latest              1c322a13e479        3 hours ago         826.6 MB
ros                 jade-ros-core       3f011f658d70        42 hours ago        812.9 MB
ros                 indigo              d2756854a026        42 hours ago        826.6 MB
ros                 indigo-ros-core     dc21afeb431b        42 hours ago        812.1 MB
```

I'd like to get this into this format:

```
<none>:<none>
crew/test:latest
ros:jade-ros-core
ros:inigo
ros:indigo-ros-core
```

How can I do this?

I can extract just the first column with: `docker images | sed 1d | cut -d" " -f1`.

Comment: `awk` is better suited to this. `cut` is only useful when the delimiter is a single character, not any amount of whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`

```
docker images | awk 'NR > 1 { print $1 ":" $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate, what platform you are running on. If your tools in /usr/bin are sufficiently new Gnu version of the tools (Linux, Cygwin), this also will do:

```
docker images|tr -s ' '|cut -d' ' -s --output-delimiter=: -f1,2
```